# Sunspot Solr Connection Refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I'm trying to add search functionality to a simple app using Sunspot_Solr, however, the connection keeps getting refused.

Here is the result I get from the error page:

```
Showing /Users/danieluribe/code/other/shouter2/app/views/searches/_search.html.erb where     line #2 raised:

Connection refused - {:data=>"fq=type%3AShout&start=0&rows=30&q=*%3A*", :method=>:post, :params=>{:wt=>:ruby}, :query=>"wt=ruby", :headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"}, :path=>"select", :uri=>#<URI::HTTP http://localhost:8983/solr/development/select?wt=ruby>, :open_timeout=>nil, :read_timeout=>nil, :retry_503=>nil, :retry_after_limit=>nil}
Extracted source (around line #11):


  def shouts
    # Shout.text_shouts.where(content_id: text_shouts)
    Shout.search do 
      fulltext @term
    end.results
  end

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/searches/show.html.erb
```

I've added both the Sunspot_Solr and Sunspot_Rails gem. I went ahead and ran the generator which created the Sunspot.yml file in the config folder.

The error is point to my model file titled Search.rb. Here is the full file reference partly above with comments removed.

```
class Search
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  attr_reader :term

  def initialize options = ()
    @term = options.fetch(:term, "")
  end

  def shouts
    Shout.search do  <--- Error points here
      fulltext @term
    end.results
 end
end
```

I went ahead and used the rake task to start Sunspot_Solr. Then I went into the console to reindex my database. I've also followed some of the questions answered here and changed the port, to no avail.

Would anyone have any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: can you add `Sunspot.config.solr.url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr'` to `config/production.rb`

Answer (score 2):

Maye be your solr server is not started use this command

rake sunspot:solr:start

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

add `Sunspot.config.solr.url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr'` to `config/production.rb`

You can reindexing

```
rake sunspot:solr:reindex RAILS_ENV=production
```

If that doesn't work...

```
rm solr/pids/production/sunspot-solr-production.pid

start solr

rake sunspot:solr:start RAILS_ENV=production
```

reindex again

```
rake sunspot:solr:reindex RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: I did have the  `Sunspot.config.solr.url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr' ` already in my config file. I ran through the other steps with no luck. I get the following: `RSolr::Error::ConnectionRefused: Connection refused ` followed by a long hash.

Comment: did you add any searchable blocks you wish to index? you can see the tutorial http://railscasts.com/episodes/278-search-with-sunspot

Comment: I was following a tutorial by Upcase and they initially did their own search functionality which worked. And then they switched to the Sunspot gem. It's a twitter clone so I was searching for shouts (tweets).

Comment: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot there is also mention for searchable blocks. You need add it for every model that you are searching.

Comment: I believe that's what I was doing in my model when I added the Shout method.

Comment: you need to pass params[:search] which will be come from view but you are passing instance variable. That is raising the problem i guess. You can take a look.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I was passing ` @term `. Working on fixing it but still getting connection error. I'll look at view next.